# Equivalent of Java static methods in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a method in a C++ class that can be called without creating an instance of the class (like a static method in Java), but I keep running into this error: `error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token`

Here's the .cpp file I'm trying to compile:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class Method {
    public:
    void printStuff(void) {
        cout << "hahaha!";
    }
};

int main(void){
    Method.printStuff(); // this doesn't work as expected!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should really get a good book. `static` member functions are a basic feature of the language.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Agreed. C++ is much too large and complicated to learn efficiently via the Internet exclusively.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In C++ it's

```
Method::printStuff();
```

and you have to declare the method as `static`.

```
class Method{
    public:
    static void printStuff(void){
        cout << "hahaha!";
    }
};
```

`::` is called the *scope resolution operator*. You can call the method with `.` if it's on a class instance, but the instance is not required (it being static and all...).