# When is it appropriate to use inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've always gotten a very direct responses along the lines of "If the child-to-be is a subtype of the parent, use inheritance." This worked while I was doing small projects, but as I started working on a 2D game engine I've run into conflicting cases.

Let’s say I have a base class GameObject, which has, for the sake of arguments, 50 functions and 5 member variables. The functions are a setters, getters, animation functions, rendering, moving and so on. It is a perfect base class for my player and enemies.

But I also have objects like items and props that only need (and I only want to be able to access) 10 of the functions inherited from GameObject. My Item can still be defined as a GameObject, but it doesn't move or have any animation.

What to do here? Do I inherit and just ignore the extra functions, creating wasted memory? 
Do I rewrite those 10 functions, wasting time? 
Do I make GameObject a private member variable of Item and Prop, once again wasting memory but allowing me to block access to any unwanted functions?
Or do I remove the needed 10 functions from GameObject and stick them in a separate header creating a library of auxiliary functions?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the replies. Pretty much everyone either said to split the GameObject class into better defined base classes or to use composition.

Comment: Ignoring functions only wastes memory if they're virtual. If they are virtual, it only wastes a very small amount of memory.

Comment: If some of your game objects don't move or animate, then it was not good design to put those functions in `GameObject`.

Comment: You could make a `PropObject` class that extends `GameObject`, overrides the 10 functions that should be ignored to throw an Exception and then extend `PropObject` from any "prop object".

Comment: [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: I had a perverted idea of using a combinations of CRTP + name hiding to accomplish what you need, but this will just get the overall design overly complicated.. and we need to make things simpler, not more complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance needs to be used very carefully. And remember this rule - always prefer composition over inheritance. This will not only simplify your code, but it will also make it more agile and unit-testable. Your Game class should not serve as a base class for your Player class. But, it may contain a Player object or a vector of them.

Keep in mind, you have to separate their functionality. Game class should not be very much aware of the the Player class. It should only know its public interface. Hence here comes the concept of interfaces. Rather than containing say a vector of Player objects, it is better to contain a vector of IPlayer interfaces. The class Player then will implement the IPlayer interface. This is handy because in the future you might want to introduce a new type of a player, in that cause you wouldn't have to modify your Game class, neither your would have to modify your Player class, but you will have a new say for instance SuperPlayer class which will once again implement the IPlayer interface.

There is tons of documentation on this topic online. But here is at least 2 rules of thumb: 1) Use interfaces wherever you can, 2) Prefer composition over inheritance.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 7):

You want to break down the functionality more

Make the GameObject only contain the very basics of what it means to be a game object. In your case this is probably the 10 critical functions.
Have Item, Prop, etc extend this directly.
Have another class, say Character, which inherits GameObject, and which has the other 40 functions that Enemy and Player both use. Then have Player and Enemy inherit from character

Answer (score 0):

you might want to consider something else rather than straight inheritance.

Have you looked into [Entity Systems](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/role-of-systems-in-entity-systems-architecture) ?

They are generally a good way to divide up your objects into exactly what you want (they do require a fair amount of inheritance though, just more divided up).

so, for instance, instead of having a strict hierarchy of GameObject -> Entity -> GroundEntity -> PlayerEntity, or something, you might instead have something like.

PlayerEntity has components: grounded, moveable, health, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A class should represent an abstraction and should be cohesive, which means that it is more focused to representing one type of entity or performing operations of the same type.

`GameObject` sounds too abstract and you may even want to drop the abstraction unless all objects in your game can be treated as GameObjects. If they can be treated as GameObjects, then GameObject should have the absolute bare minimum that all objects in your game can do. If not, drop the abstraction.

From what you mentioned, it seems like the operations that you want to "inherit" from GameObject could actually belong in a `Utility` class. The Utility class will have [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333754/equivalent-of-java-static-methods-in-c) methods that can be used by any other class that needs a similar operation.