# c++ - Count number of instantiations of a class

Tags: java, c++

I have a simple C++ example where I am attempting to count the number of instances of a class. I am basing this off of an old Java example, and am confused why this is not working. I am only attempting to access `static` members of a class, yet compilation fails.

Why is my default constructor causing compilation errors, along with my attempt to make a "static" function that returns a static member variable?

I am effectively attempting to create a function within a class that can be called like a global function, without declaring it external to the class like a traditional C function.

Thank you.

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
   public:
      static int iMyInt;
      static int getMyInt();
};

MyClass::MyClass() {
   this.iMyInt = 0;
}

static int MyClass::getMyInt() {
   return iMyInt;
}

int main(void) {
   int someInt = MyClass::getMyInt();
   cout << "My Int " << someInt << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output - Build**

---

```
test.cpp:10:18: error: definition of implicitly-declared 'MyClass::MyClass()'
 MyClass::MyClass() {
                  ^
test.cpp:14:30: error: cannot declare member function 'static int MyClass::getMyInt()' to have static linkage [-fpermissive]
 static int MyClass::getMyInt() {
                              ^
```

**Edit**

---

This is my final (working) code listing after using the suggestions here and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333754/equivalent-of-java-static-methods-in-c):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
   public:
      MyClass();
      static int iMyInt;
      static int getMyInt();
};
int MyClass::iMyInt = 0;

MyClass::MyClass() {
   //this.iMyInt = 0;
   cout << "I am a new class" << endl;
}

int MyClass::getMyInt() {
   return iMyInt;
}

int main(void) {
   MyClass* someClass = new MyClass();

   int someInt = MyClass::getMyInt();
   cout << "My Int " << someInt << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You are probably looking for this](https://eval.in/185889).

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass()
    {
      instances++;
      showInstanceCount();
    }

    virtual ~MyClass()
    {
      instances--;
      showInstanceCount();
    }

    static int getInstanceCount()
    {
      return instances;
    }

    static void showInstanceCount()
    {
      cout << "MyClass instance count: " << instances << endl;
    }

    static int instances;
};

int MyClass::instances = 0;

int main()
{
  { MyClass a, b, c; }
  return 0;
}
```

[Output from sample code](https://eval.in/185889):

```
MyClass instance count: 1
MyClass instance count: 2
MyClass instance count: 3
MyClass instance count: 2
MyClass instance count: 1
MyClass instance count: 0
```

Comment: New to cpp here: Why is `int MyClass::instances = 0;` outside the class ? Can't you initialize it to zero inside the class ?

Answer (score 2):

Static methods don't have access to `this` because they don't have any knowledge about exsisting objects of the class. 
Change

```
this.iMyInt = 0
```

to

```
MyClass::iMyInt++; //if you want to count number of instances. It's not necessery to zeroing static variables. They are initiated by 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first error, You have not declared the constructor in the class. You have to declare the constructor in the class.

```
class MyClass {
   public:
      MyClass();                // Declare the consructor
      static int iMyInt;
      static int getMyInt();
};
```

For the second problem, while defining the function don't include the static keyword. So, instead of

```
static int MyClass::getMyInt() {
   return iMyInt;
}
```

change it to

```
int MyClass::getMyInt() {
   return iMyInt;
}
```

Finally, you need to define the `iMyInt` static data member, in addition to declaring it:

```
int MyClass::iMyInt = 0;
```

Note that there is no `static` here as well.